# MVC - FileContentResult sends corrupted pdf

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-8

I have a simple action method that returns a PDF document, that gets shown in an `<iframe>` with an `<embed>` tag, and every few calls to this method will return a corrupted PDF. (I've determined its corrupted by using dev tools to save the response from the server)

Action Method:

```
public FileContentResult GetPdfReport(string Id)
{
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=report.pdf");
    var content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/Reports/Testfile.pdf"));
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/Reports/debugReport.pdf"), content);
    return File(content, "application/pdf");
}
```

View Content:

```
<embed id="widgetResponsePdf" src="@Url.Action("GetPdfReport", "WidgetResponse", new { Id = "123" })" type="application/pdf" onmouseout="mouseOutHandler();" />
```

The files TestFile.pdf and debugReport.pdf open just fine when I get a corrupted PDF, and there is no difference in the request and response header between the normal request/response and the corrupted request/response.

Is there some setting in IIS that I am missing that could be causing the inconsistent behavior between requests, or could this be caused solely by a network issue?

Comment: I'm not sure, but try to set `content.Position=0;` before return string

Comment: thanks but content is a byte array, not a stream

Comment: Are you sure that PDF is correct? Also, try to change FileContentResult to ActionResult

Comment: Hi @AleksejVasinov, as mentioned in my question, the only PDF I cannot open is the one I get from the `FileContentResult` when I examine the response in the browser dev tools and Fiddler. Also, what significant differecnce would there be that would warrant using `ActionResult `over `FileContentResult` in this case?

Comment: @elliot-j did you figured something out?

Comment: @BendEg sorry I totally forgot about this question, I've updated this with the solution we eventually settled on but this is more of a hack in my opinion rather than an actual solution.

Answer (score 1):

In our case, the IFrame has a **src** attribute that points to a partial view that loads the `<embed>` content, which then has a **src** attribute that points to the actual PDF file instead of a `PartialView` that returns a `FileContentResult`. The example below has been simplified from our actual implementation
**Partial View**

```
<iframe> <!-- iframe is actually loaded from another partial view, it is show here to simplify things -->
    <embed 
         src='@Url.Content(Model.ReportFileName)' 
         type="application/pdf">
    </embed>
</iframe>
```

**Controller**

```
public PartialView GetPdfReport(string Id)
{
    var model = PDFResponseModel 
    {
        ReportFileName = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/Testfile.pdf")
    };
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

Due to a site restriction for IE support, our users (intranet site) are required to have AdobeAcrobat installed to view PDF's. While this solution works for us, this may not be desirable for internet facing websites.